# Return additional variable from Hibernate Query

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following query in my Hibernate repository:

```
@Query("SELECT house FROM House house WHERE (6371 * acos(cos(radians((:oLat))) * cos(radians(house.lat)) * cos(radians(house.lng) - radians((:oLng))) + sin (radians((:oLat))) * sin(radians(house.lat)))) < (:dist)")
List<House> findByLatLng(@Param("oLat") Double oLat, @Param("oLng")Double oLng, @Param("dist")Double dist);
```

Which returns me a list of houses within certain distance from the origin. Now, what can I do, to also store and return the value of (distance from the origin to the given record):

```
6371 * acos(cos(radians((:oLat))) * cos(radians(house.lat)) * cos(radians(house.lng) - radians((:oLng))) + sin (radians((:oLat))) * sin(radians(house.lat))))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not gonna write to your particular example, but something like this:

```sql
SELECT something
  FROM (SELECT (personId * 78) AS something
          FROM people) alias
 WHERE something < 12345
```